# When I Use Assert.Pass() inside teardown, it marks the testcase as fail? i am using LatestNunit Version

Tags: nunit, assertions

When I Use Assert.Pass() inside teardown, it marks the testcase as fail? i am using LatestNunit Version

it was working fine before upgrading nUnit!

Comment: What does you code look like? What does the failure look like, is it throwing an error, or does the assertion fail?

Comment: just a simple function inside teardown contains only assert.pass();  failure is that testcase marked as failed in test explorer with the following message : Teardown : Nunit.Framework.successException :                                as far i know successException should mark the testcase as pass

Answer (score 0):

It looks like ResultStateExceptions are explicitly not supported in the `TearDown` - see this comment in the source code.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// RecordTearDownException appends the message and stacktrace
    /// from an exception arising during teardown of the test
    /// to any previously recorded information, so that any
    /// earlier failure information is not lost. Note that
    /// calling Assert.Ignore, Assert.Inconclusive, etc. during
    /// teardown is treated as an error. If the current result
    /// represents a suite, it may show a teardown error even
    /// though all contained tests passed.
    /// </summary>
```

https://github.com/nunit/nunit/blob/ca8dc9fefa33be11f85cc1c8d2cf14e0fef51117/src/NUnitFramework/framework/Internal/Results/TestResult.cs#L508

That seems sensible - I'm not sure what situation you're in where you want to force your failing tests to show as passing? If you have a genuine usecase for this, I'd suggest posting a Github issue to discuss it as a feature, but it doesn't sound like the ideal approach.